# Uniformly convergent in topology

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X-A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i$ is an open $G_\sigma$-set, i.e., $F_i$ are opens, in a normal space $X$. Then by Urysohn's lemma, for each i, there exists a continuous function $f_i:X\longrightarrow [0,1]$ such that

$$f_i(x)=0 \text{ for } x\in A  \text{ and } f_i(x)=1 \text{ for } x\in F_i.$$
Now define $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}f_i(x)$.
My question is why $\{f_i\}$ uniformly convergent to $f(x)$? To specific, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $k$ such that $|f(x)-f_i(x)|<\varepsilon$ for every $x\in X$ and $i\geq k$.

Comment: You mean that the series converges uniformly, and thus has a continuous sum function $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply not true. Use that 
$$\sup_{x\in X} \left\vert \frac{1}{2^i}f_i (x) \right\vert =\frac{1}{2^i}.$$
If $(f_i)_{i\geq 1}$ would converge to $f$, this would imply that $f=0$.
What is true (use the triangular inequality) is that the following:
$$ \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left\Vert f -  \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{2^i}f_i 
\right\Vert_{\sup} = 0.$$
I.e. the partial sum converge uniformly to $f$.

Comment: Another question: is it a continuous map from X to $[0,1]$. Actually it is a proof of the result: a subset $A$ of a normal space $X$ is a closed $G_\delta$-set, then there exists a continuous function $f:X\longrightarrow I$ such that $A=f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Indeed, this proves that $f$ is continuous (as it is the uniform limit of continuous functions). Also, you have (as the $f_i$ are nonnegative) that $$f^{-1}(\{0\})= \bigcap_{i\geq 1} f_i^{-1}(\{0\}) .$$

Comment: Thank you very much. According to your answer, a summary as follows: define new continuous maps $g_n=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{1}{2^i}f_i$, then (1) $g_n$ is continuous, and (2) $g_n$ uniformly converge to $f$. Thus $f$ is continuous.

Comment: This is exactly the way you should do it.

Comment: By the way, in case you think my post answers your question, you can accept it. Of course you can also wait till a better answer is given.

Comment: it's my first time to use this, is it now accepted ?

Comment: Yes, you can see it from the green check mark :)